# Is there a way to find out if two strings are similar in SQL Server without knowing anything about the values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to put together something that pulls related items based off a primary item.

For example, say I've got a really simple *[FRUIT]* table:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Fuji Apples |
| 2 | Apple: Golden Delicious |
| 3 | Granny Smith Apple |
| 4 | Blood Orange |
| 5 | Orange: Mandarin |

And the user is currently looking at "Fuji Apples". I want to return the rows for "Apple: Golden Delicious" and "Granny Smith Apple" because they also have the word "Apple" in the value of their *[Name]* column. I guess what I'm looking for is something like *LIKE*, that does a broader comparison of the strings to see if there's any similar sets of characters.

---

I've taken a look at *SOUNDEX* and *DIFFERENCE*, but they're not what I'm looking for as my strings are too long and the similar word could be anywhere in the string.

If there's nothing that's fine, I can always implement some similarity algorithm if needed; but I don't want to put in the effort if there's already built-in to t-sql.

**Note:** I am aware in the example above it would make more sense to just add another column and/or table that had the values "Apple" and "Orange"; but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Sounds like you should have a table of "keywords", and then a junction table to link your data above and your keywords. Then you can return any other rows that share 1 or more keywords.

Comment: Full Text Search combined with `semanticsimilaritytable` might get you what you want, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/semanticsimilaritytable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML, XQuery, and Quantified Expressions.

Useful link: [Quantified Expressions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/quantified-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, fruit VARCHAR(200));
INSERT INTO @tbl (fruit) VALUES
('Fuji Apples'),
('Apple: Golden Delicious'),
('Granny Smith Apple'),
('Blood Orange'),
('Orange: Mandarin');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1)
    , @searchFor VARCHAR(30) = 'Fuji Apple';

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('some $r in /root/source/r/text()
                satisfies contains(data(/root/target)[1], $r)', 'BIT') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><source><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@searchFor, @Separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></source>'
      + '<target><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(fruit, @Separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></target></root>' AS XML)
      ) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------+--------+
| ID |          fruit          | Result |
+----+-------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Fuji Apples             |      1 |
|  2 | Apple: Golden Delicious |      1 |
|  3 | Granny Smith Apple      |      1 |
|  4 | Blood Orange            |      0 |
|  5 | Orange: Mandarin        |      0 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Doesn't 100% fulfill my needs, but is the perfect jumping off point. Thank you!